# Is there a way to ignore racial and regional prerequisites for feats and/or classes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, races, prestige-class

Is there a way to ignore racial prerequisites for feats and/or classes?

A few examples: 
Shiba protector (Oriental Adventures p. 222) needs you to be Human (Phoenix).

Darkwood Stalker (Complete Warrior p. 23) needs you to be elf or half-elf.

Ankheg Tribe Ambush (Shining south p.19 needs you to be Human (the Shaar)

Many of the race locked classes have a adaptation (Like the Battlesmith - Races of stone p.97), but not all of them. Is it possible to go around those prerequisites and if yes, what is the smoothest way to do so?

Comment: There was a reason I left it as a comment because I could not remember the source even enough to track it down

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, some form of polymorph effect would allow you to qualify for a prestige class, and you only need to qualify in order to take the first level, so if you manage to level up with such an effect, you could take that level and then ignore it from then on.

Not many DMs will let you do that, including me: I would much rather waive the racial prerequisite on the class than set the precedent of allowing such shenanigans. But RAW, it would be one approach for prestige classes. It does not help for feats, since you need to meet the requirements for those to use them as well as to select them.

If the race required is one of the “races of stone,” that is dwarf, gnome, or goliath, the Stoneblessed prestige class from *Races of Stone* allows you to count as one of those races as its capstone. The class is pretty easy to enter by 3rd level, and only three levels long, so you can have the class finished by 5th and thus be eligible to take the race-locked prestige class starting at 6th, assuming you meet the other requirements. Unfortunately, its other class features are pretty mediocre, so you would have to be in a really specific situation where it’s better than either just being the required race or skipping the prestige class.

Stoneblessed *also* includes an adaptation section, suggesting that it could be adapted for use to qualify for *any* race, just by creating class features for that racial choice matching those availble for those looking to count as dwarves, gnomes, or goliaths. It even gives tips on the kinds of things these should be.

But beyond that, you are out of luck: I am not aware of any similar options in all of 3.5. Even the similar three-level elf-friend prestige class in *Races of the Wild*, the ruathar, does not have that same feature for elves.

Comment: Some of the examples are not racial, but regional. Could you improve your answer including them as well?

Comment: @Momonga-sama Frankly, it might be better to split this into separate questions; you have a lot going on here (feats and prestige classes, races and regions). I can try to find things on regional feats, but it will take me time to find anything, while a separate question could be answered by someone more familiar with those rules.